# SQLite Access is denied - works local but not public

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, subsonic, system.data.sqlite, spatialite

when i access my ASP.Net IIS site (W2K3) from i get the following error:

`SQLite error
Access is denied.`

[SQLiteException (0x80004005): SQLite error Access is denied.]

It happens when i call:

`Object retVal = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand("SELECT load_extension('libspatialite-4.dll');", conn).ExecuteScalar();`

When i use Visual Studio all works perfectly.

So in that case i can rule out any dll problems. All non-spatial SQLIte queries work fine from IIS and Visual Studio too.

I'm sure i have to set a permission setting somewhere, but where and what user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the Spatiallite folder is in *your* path and not in the *system* path.  Also double check the user ID that is used for IIS.  It could be different from ASP.NET.

If that doesn't work try monitoring on the server with process monitor http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645 Watch for the permission denied error and you should be headed down the right path.